How to make a transaction with different tokens
i'm creating a cashapp clone with solana and SolanaPay in JavaScript (NodeJS) i'm a newbie developing with Solana, how can i make a transaction with different solana tokens, for example bonk, pambicoin etc...

Does this answer your question? How do I transfer an SPL token using web3.js?
